# Can't locate wallpaper when saved from browser

Tags: wallpaper

I have read multiple questions on here but none seem to work for my phone.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 2.3.3.

I really need the photo that's my wallpaper. I can't locate it on the phone or the location on   the Internet.

Background info: I was browsing the Internet on my phone. I clicked on a photo on a website and clicked "set as wallpaper", which it did. Now however I can't find the photo anywhere on my phone. (It is still set as my wallpaper though.)

Answer (score 3):

Most Android phones come with an app called "Downloads" where you can find any file you may have downloaded from the internet. From there, you should be able to view the picture and set it as your background through the `Menu` key settings.

Another way might be to look in your `Gallery` application (or any photo viewer). Most of these will display the Downloads folder (or any folder that holds image files), where you can view the image and set it as your background.

Worst case scenario, I'd look in your browser settings to see if you can find a folder path for where it is saving downloaded information (again, ususally `/sdcard/downloads`) and use a file manager (like [X-plore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en)) to find and open the file, where you will be able to set it as your wallpaper.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. the image is not stored in the downloads folder. every image i have saved is stored there. however on this occasion i didnt save it, i directly clicked set as wallpaper, which it did.  i cant even use the screen capture function to copy it as it is set cover the "7" windows ... (so it moves as you swipe through the menu)

Answer (score 1):

I developed "Wallpaper Saver" to save wallpapers when I have thrown away the original. Get it from Play: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.alroe.apps.WallpaperSaverFree